# How can I show instruction addresses in a kernel Call Trace?

Tags: linux

How can I show the addresses `[<XXXXXXXX>]` in the call trace when e.g. a kernel module causes an oops? I have been searching for some kernel configuration option without much luck.

**my dmesg output**

```
...
[26246.257523] Call Trace:
[26246.257530]  do_one_initcall+0x59/0x240
[26246.257540]  do_init_module+0x5c/0x230
[26246.257545]  load_module+0x2725/0x29e0
[26246.257556]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xbb/0x120
[26246.257560]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xbb/0x120
[26246.257567]  do_syscall_64+0x4e/0x150
[26246.257573]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[26246.257577] RIP: 0033:0x7f3680ff5f8d
...
```

**some other dmesg output with addresses**

```
...
Call Trace:
 [<c010102d>] ? _stext+0x2d/0x170
 [<c01708e4>] ? __vunmap+0xa4/0xf0
 [<c0170981>] ? vfree+0x21/0x30
 [<c014b698>] ? load_module+0x19b8/0x1a40
 [<c035e965>] ? __mutex_unlock_slowpath+0xd5/0x140
 [<c0140da6>] ? trace_hardirqs_on_caller+0x106/0x150
 [<c014b7aa>] ? sys_init_module+0x8a/0x1b0
 [<c0140da6>] ? trace_hardirqs_on_caller+0x106/0x150
 [<c0240a08>] ? trace_hardirqs_on_thunk+0xc/0x10
 [<c0103407>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x43
...
```

edit: It's for kernel version 4.19. According to this page https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/admin-guide/bug-hunting.html , I think it should be visible in a debug Kernel, however DEBUG_KERNEL, DEBUG_INFO, KALLSYMS and KALLSYMS_ALL are all turned on for me.

edit2: I'm starting to think it was printed in older kernels and not anymore in more recent kernels if I look at the code in dumpstack.c